# Algorithm for swapping all cube edges or corners cyclically (PLL)

Tags: rubiks-cube, twisty-puzzles

What's the algorithm for this PLL case? In order words how can I swap the edges (or corners) in a cyclical way (like A or U perm, but with all edges or corners)?

[image: what the pll]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do a 4-cycle of edges without affecting anything else, because only permutations with an [even parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation) can be performed.

Note however that on your cube the centres are also incorrect. If you shift the middle layer to the right one quarter turn to put its centres correct, then its edge pieces become the incorrect ones. You then have 8 incorrect edges, needing two 4-cycles to become solved. That is an even permutation, and can be done.

Maybe you were actually trying to create a 4-spot pattern, solving directly to it. Unfortunately that particular 4-spot pattern (with a 4-cycle of centres) is an odd permutation and therefore not possible. The only achievable 4-spot pattern has the centres in one layer turned 180 degrees (i.e. opposite centres swapped, which is an even permutation).